# Maximize function: what method?

Tags: python, language-agnostic, max, mathematical-optimization

I have a function which looks like this: `f(x) = min(f_1(x_1), ..., f_n(x_n))` where `n` is about 10 and all `f_i` are positive monotonic, smooth, and their values are almost always (for all `x_i` for all `f_i`) are different less than by a factor of ten. So they seem to be rather good for analysing.
What's the best (fast?) way to maximize it having such constrains:
- all `x_i` are integers and less than ~100
- product of all `x_i` should lie near a specified value (assume, not further than 10% from it)

Algorithm description in any language is appreciated, but if it is in Python, then it's ten times better :)

P.S.: earlier I've worked with genetic algorithms, and first applied them to this task. However, it doesn't seem to be the best choice: GAs are quite slow, also I couldn't think of efficient crossover operation for this problem.

Comment: What do your f_i functions look like, what do they do?

Comment: Um, what's the definition of *monotonic* again? If it means what I think it means, `min(f_1(x), f_1(x+abs(C))) == f_1(x)`. Doesn't that make this a trivial question?

Comment: I think he meant that each individual function is monotonic, and there n different functions.

Comment: @kojiro I meant each function is monotonic (what you've written is true, of course), and there is no (simple) relationship among them.

Comment: @chersanya Then there is simply no way to generalize a solution. `lambda x: x` and `lambda x: 2*x` are both positive monotonic functions, but which is `f_1` and which is `f_2`?

Comment: @Trufa those functions are smooth, positive monotonic, and their values are almost always (for all `x_i` for all `f_i`) are different less than by a factor of ten. So they seem to be rather good for analysing.

Comment: @chersanya Would you please edit your question to include any relevant descriptions of the functions (such as your previous comment)?

Comment: @kojiro I can't understand what do you mean (in previous comment). There are many algorithms that maximize/minimize very general case of functions, but each algorithm has own pros and cons. The functions are defined (at runtime), so the program knows them.

Comment: @chersanya can you elaborate on the initial conditions of the x_is?

Comment: @user931794 what initial conditions do you mean? What I have is n those functions and constrains on the vector x, no initial values.

Comment: @chersanya I don't know how to be clearer, but I think the burden of *clarity* needs to be on you. As it stands, I think the only solution is simply the `min` of the results of each function, without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't immediately see a better solution than simply choosing a starting point randomly, evaluating each function f_i with each input x_i, determining the minimum input, and then incrementing the input of the function that gave the lowest result. It's not elegant, it's not complex, but it's a good baseline brute force approach.

```
int (**f_is)(int n);

//...

int xs[10];

//...

while(true) {
    int i = 0;

    int cmin = f_is[0](i);
    int cminIndex = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        int cfunc = (f_is[i])(i);

        if(cmin < cfunc) {
            cmin = cfunc;
            cminIndex = i;
        }
    }

    ++xs[cminIndex];
}
```

EDIT: a couple more things: if you compute f_i(n_i) in parallel and the join and take the min, it'll be a lot faster but you still need a way to communicate the index of the function that produced the smallest value back to the caller. I would recommend Haskell as a great language to write this in because it's way *way* faster than python and in some cases you can get great concurrency support without much effort.

Comment: Not related to this problem, but after your answer I've started learning haskell. There were many interesting things about it, but your note about its performance was the decisive factor.

Comment: great to hear that that my comment made a difference. Haskell is truly an excellent and mind expanding language.